# Split by delimiter using xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, tokenize

This is my XML:

```
<LIGHT_DESCRIPTION>
    <LIGHT_CHARACTERISTICS>Q+LFl</LIGHT_CHARACTERISTICS>
    <LIGHT_SIGNAL_GROUP>(6)(1)</LIGHT_SIGNAL_GROUP>
</LIGHT_DESCRIPTION>
```

For me is necessary split by character '+' :

at  Q is referred --> (6)

at  LF1 is referred --> (1)

This is the output using XSLT 1.0:

```
Q (6)  -  LF1 (1)
```

Comment: Your example does not expound the logic of the transformation.

Comment: Still not clear, I am afraid. How many "pairs" can there be?

Comment: The pair dipend of Light_characteristics, can be the number of '+' + 1.

Comment: exemple if I count two '+' signs there are 3 'pairs'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/LIGHT_DESCRIPTION">
    <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
        <xsl:with-param name="names" select="LIGHT_CHARACTERISTICS"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="values" select="LIGHT_SIGNAL_GROUP"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="names"/>
    <xsl:param name="values"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($names, '+')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($names, '+')"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($values, ')')"/>
            <xsl:text>) - </xsl:text>
             <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                        <xsl:with-param name="names" select="substring-after($names, '+')"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="values" select="substring-after($values, ')')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($names, ' ', $values)"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note: IMHO, you are exchanging one bad format for another just as bad. Why don't you take this opportunity to produce output in an established format, such as .csv for example?